# What is the first value of scale in the scale space construction for SIFT?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, scale, feature-extraction, sift

The scale space for SIFT algorithm is constructed by convolving an image with a sequence of gaussians as below:

[image]

where G(x,y,s) is the gaussian kernel (s is the scale parameter) and I(x,y) is the image.

**My question is:** what is the first value of scale s that we use to create the first laplacian image in the first octave?

My understanding is that scale = 0 represents the original image itself. How do we select the first scale value?

Comment: You can set scale parameter experimentally because it's in customizing area. I usually use 0, sqrt(1/2), 1, sqrt(2), 2.

Comment: So I set the scale depending on the number of divisions of each octave? So if the octave has k+1 divisions, the first one should be 2^(1/k), the next 2^(2/k), so on to 2^1?

Comment: Could you specify "`division`"?

Comment: It's not an answer but here is my parameters to build a scale space for getting `keypoints`. Octave-k: 0, σk, 2σk, 3σk, 4σk. σ=sqrt(1/2)

Comment: division = number of images within an octave

Comment: Then,, I can recommend these parameters. `d=Division` `σ=sqrt(1/2)` `Octave-k: 0, σk, 2σk, ...,  (d-1)σk`

Comment: L(x,y,s) is not the laplacian. it's a **level** in the **gaussian** pyramid. the equation itself tells you what it is, the image convolved with a gaussian (lowpass) kernel. that can't possibly be a laplacian. you must have misinterpreted the letter

Comment: corrected the error related to the Laplacian

Comment: ok now your question boils down to the nyquist limit for a given sigma, if I may be so sloppy, or the converse of that, i.e. what's the sigma required for a given sampling period to avoid aliasing. you are looking for _some_ cut-off frequency. -- you could also just browse some SIFT implementations, or the paper, and maybe the specifics are defined sufficiently there.

Comment: the usual "base" pyramid decimates by two (in each dimension) for each level, with preceding lowpass to avoid aliasing of course. SIFT uses intermediate sigmas, starting from each base level, because steps of 2 are quite large. -- opencv's pyrDown uses a gaussian-like kernel that is close to a gaussian with sigma=1, before decimation, which agrees with the hieroglyphs found on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_filter

Comment: would you appreciate me turning that into an answer? you can be sure that some mathematically more gifted entity will swoop in and correct me the moment I do

Comment: the scale pyramid MUST NOT be using a linearly spaced sequence of sigmas (factors 0,1,2,3,...). it must be linearly spaced *in the logarithm*, i.e. exponentially spaced in linear space. it must be something^k for whatever factor you choose. the basic power-of-2 pyramid would use sigma=2^k (with whatever weighting factor). you can get intermediate levels by choosing non-integer k, like 0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1, ...